# how to render a nested array and string in an object which is further nested in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, next.js

I am trying to render the data called items in nextjs and I have been debugging it for a while. below is my code that causes the error. the goal is to render the descriptions in an array as alist and render the description that is a string as it is but i can not use the map function because of the fist description(which is a string). I am also trying to not use dangerouslysetinnerhtml.

```
export default function SingleCareerContainer(){
  const items = [
    {
      title: "About",
      description:
        "We are developing new functionality for an application },
    {
      title: "Requirements",
      description: [
        "3+ years of working experience.",
        "Extensive experience in Swift. ",
        "mobile development life cycle.",
        "good communication skills.",
      ],
    },
    {
      title: "Responsibilities",
      description: [
        "write program code according to the defined application architecture.",
        "Implement code refactoring. ",
        "refactoring and optimization results. ",
        "Develop, document, and edit programming interfaces.",
        "Estimating tasks .",
      ],
    },
    {
      title: "What we Offer",
      description: [
        "Above average compensation.",
        "Close cooperation.",
        "Challenging tasks. ",
      ],
    },
  ];

   for (const item of items) {
    let rep = item.description;
    if(rep.length > 1){
     
      const ree = rep.map((reps, i) => {
        return(
          <Text key={i}>{reps}</Text>
        )
      })
    }else{
    return(ree);
    }

  const itemcomp = items.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <p>
            {item.title}
          </p>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  });
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
            <p>
              Frontend Developer
            </p>
            <Button width={"auto"} height={"60px"}>
              Apply
            </Button>
          <>
            <p>
              <div>{itemcomp}</div>
              {ree}
            </p>
          </>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
      `
```

Answer (score 0):

A string is also an array under the hood so you can't reliably distinguish between an array and a string with `.length` property. You need to use `typeof` operator because an array has `'object'` value while string has `'string'` value if you apply it to both types.

Pseudo-code:

```
if (typeof description === 'string') {
  return description
} else {
  return description.map(item => <Text>item</Text>)
}
```

Comment: Javascript says no- `Array.isArray("hello")  // false`

Comment: Of course it won't, similar to how `typeof` says it's a `string`, but under the hood it's an array.

Comment: this doesnot work either.

Comment: what doesn't work?